# Run Macro from prior date workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Every day I create a "Dashboard" and I am trying to include a week over week variance in the dashboard. The Dashboards are all named "MM.DD.YY Dashboard". Is there any way to have a macro automatically pull data from the Dashboard dated 7 days prior? For instance, on 11/18 I am trying to pull the data from "11.11.14 Dashboard".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Indirect` to pull a reference to a created spreadsheet.
For example, if the previous date is in A1, then a reference to the previous week data could be

```
=INDIRECT("'" & A1 & " Dashboard'!B7)
```

If you want excel to work out the previous date, then there is a formula you can use, using `Cell` and string slicing.
Put this formula in a cell, and it will find out the current workbook date, subtract 7, and display the info in the format needed for sheet references

```
="'" & TEXT(DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(MID(CELL("filename"),FIND("]",CELL("filename"))+1,256),8),".","/"))-7,"mm.dd.yy") &" Dashboard'!"
```

you can then use this in a simpler looking indirect:

```
=Indirect(A1 & "B7")
```